How is Krippendorff's alpha defined when expected disagreement is 0?
I'm wondering what is the definition of Krippendorff's Alpha statistics when the expected disagreement is 0?
The general form of Krippendorff's Alpha is:
$\alpha = 1 - \frac{D_{o}}{D_{e}}$
I'm currently using NLTK's implmentation of Krippendorff's Alpha, nltk.metrics.agreement (s. Source Code) and calculate the confidence interval using bootstrapping (1000 randomly selecting items from the original data with replacement until the sample size).
During bootstrapping, some samples are drawn where the coders perfectly agree and hence the expected disagreement is 0. The NLTK currently throws a Division by Zero Error. How should I correctly deal with this situation? Please provide sources if you know the answer.
